# Angular2 sort array of objects based the order of another array of objects using a pipe

Tags: arrays, sorting, angular, typescript, pipe

I have a pipe that filters an array based on the objects contained in another array.  How do I sort the filtered array (array1) based on the order of the array I am using to filter against (array2)?

```
import { Injectable, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'arrayFilter'
})
@Injectable()
export class AttributeFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(array: any[], filterFrom: any[]): any {
    array.filter(item => filterFrom.some(f => f.value == item.value));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilize the native [`Array.prototype.sort()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) for this:

```
array.sort((a, b) => {
  let fromValues = filterFrom.map(f => f.value);
  return fromValues.indexOf(a.value) < fromValues.indexOf(b.value) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

In the snippet above, the `fromValue` array is created so that we can use the [`.indexOf()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) in order to get the index of an item in the `filterFrom` array based on a given value. From there, the sort method takes care of the rest and reorders the items in the `array` array based on the `value` property relative to the corresponding value's position in the `filterFrom` array.

You can just chain the `.sort()` method logic after the `.filter()` method; just remember to return the result.

```
import { Injectable, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'arrayFilter'
})
@Injectable()
export class AttributeFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(array: any[], filterFrom: any[]): any {
    return array.filter(item => filterFrom.some(f => f.value === item.value))
                .sort((a, b) => {
                  let fromValues = filterFrom.map(f => f.value);
                  return fromValues.indexOf(a.value) <
                         fromValues.indexOf(b.value) ? -1 : 1;
                });

  }
}
```